# Advanced search options in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I would like to create advanced search option in PHP. I am retrieving values based on dropdown boxes and radio buttons. I would like to know how to generate query based on these, like how to get the values from listboxes and radio buttons in the first place. Second thing is I would like to know how to include multiple variable in the query or just leave a query completely blank.

For example:
I should Filter by component type which contains (R, Mahout, Storm, Python, Splunk)
Component domain (telecom, utility, retail, BFSI, travel, Health care)
Usage rights (intellectual property, no rights)
then miscellaneous values like sort alphabetically, by version etc.

The problem is multiple values can be selected from component domain and component type. Or it can be left empty. How do i search based on what is chosen? and if there are multiple values how do i modify my query for the php accordingly?

I have pasted the code below: Can you guide me like atleast give me an example query on how to generate query for component type and generate multiple values for it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("cerebra", $con);
$sql="select name from details";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$query=mysql_query($sql,$con);
$names=array();
$index=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $names[$index]=$row[0];
    $index++;

}

?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>;
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
<style type="text/css">

.basictab{
padding: 3px 0;
margin-left: 0;
font: bold 16px Sans-serif;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: left; /*set to left, center, or right to align the menu as desired*/
}

.basictab li{
display: inline;
margin: 0;
}
.basictab li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #2d2b2b;
}

.basictab li a:visited{
    color: #00F;
}

.basictab li a:hover{
color: #C60;
}

.basictab li a:active{
color: black;
}

.basictab a:selected{ /*selected tab effect*/
position: relative;
top: 1px;
padding-top: 4px;
background-color: #DBFF6C;
color: #06F;
}
fieldset{

  padding: 1em;
  font:90%/1 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  }

</style>
<script>
function view(){
    document.getElementById("view").style.display="";
}
function auth(){
    var pwd=prompt("Enter the password:","Password")
}
function hide(){
    document.getElementById("view").style.diplay="none";}
</script>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.multiselect.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css" />
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/prettify.css" />-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/prettify.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect();
});
</script>
</head>

<body onload="hide(); prettyPrint();" id="test" >
<div><h1 style="font-family:Geneva, sans-serif; color:#036">Component Registry</h1></div>
<div id=tab>
<ul class="basictab">
<li><a href="search.php">SEARCH</a></li>
<li><a href="add.php">ADD</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="search"></label>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
    <a id=2 href="#" onclick="view()">Search</a>
  </p>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Filter by:</legend>
  <div id=1>
  <table><tr><td><p>
    <label>Component Type:</label></td>
    <td><select title="Basic example" multiple="multiple" name="example-basic" size="5">
    <option value="option1">Sgoop</option>
    <option value="option2">Monet</option>
    <option value="option3">Hive</option>
    <option value="option4">Mahout</option>
    <option value="option5">R</option>
    <option value="option6">Storm</option>
    <option value="option7">Flume</option>
    <option value="option8">Solr</option>
    <option value="option9">Python</option>
    <option value="option10">Splunk</option>
    <option value="option11">Ruby</option>
    <option value="option12">perl</option>
    </select>
  </p></td></tr>
 <tr><td><p>
    <label>Component Domain:</label></td>

    <td><select title="Basic example" multiple="multiple" name="examplebasic2" size="5">
    <option value="Telecom">Telecom</option>
    <option value="Utility">Utility</option>
    <option value="BFSI">BFSI</option>
    <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
    <option value="Health Care">Health Care</option>
    <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
    <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
    <option value="Government">Government</option>
    <option value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
    <option value="Education">Education</option>
    </select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><p>Usage Rights:</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="right" value="right" />
    <label for="right">Intellectual Property</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="right2" value="right2" />
    <label for="right2">No rights reserved</label>
  </p></td></tr>
  <tr><td><p>Miscellaneous:</td> 
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio3" id="misc" value="misc" />
    <label for="misc">Sort Alphabetically</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="misc2" value="misc" />
    <label for="misc2">Sort by Upload date</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="misc3" value="misc3" />
    <label for="misc3">Sort by Versions</label>
  </p></td></tr>
  </table> </div></fieldset>
  <div id="view" style="display:none">
  <table width="457" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="117">Component Name</td>
      <td width="59">Type</td>
      <td width="60">Domain</td>
      <td width="56">Rights</td>
      <td width="72">Download</td>
      <td width="53">Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="radio" id="12" value="1"  />
      <label for="12"></label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="radio" id="122" value="1"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="radio" id="2" value="2 />
      <label for="2"></label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="radio" id="123" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="1" id="13" value="Download" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="13" id="132" value="Delete" onclick="auth()" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put it together in some sort of query.  I don't know what you're using, but assuming it's a simple MySQL statement I would do something like this

```
$component_domain = isset($_GET['component_domain']) ? ' AND component_domain = '.$_GET['component_domain'] : '';
$component_type = isset($_GET['component_type']) ? ' AND component_type = '.$_GET['component_type'] : '';
$sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? ' SORT BY '.$_GET['sort'].' '.$_GET['sort_direction'] : '';
$stmt = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = "somevalue"'.$component_domain.$component_type.$sort;
```

then run your query.  Not my best work, but you can modify it as needed.

Comment: Can you just check my code and suggest me how to include? atleast for domain or type